# Gradle: Task with path not found in project

Tags: java, gradle, javaagents

I have a gradle project with the following structure:

```
rootDir
|--agent-v1.0.0
   |--agent.jar
|--proj1
   |-- // other project files
   |--build.gradle
|--proj2
   |-- // other project files
   |--build.gradle
|--build.gradle
```

I would like to run `test.jvmArgs = ['javaagent:agent-v1.0.0/agent.jar']` for all subprojects, so I wrote the following task in the root `build.gradle`:

```
subprojects {
    task cs {
        outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
        dependsOn test.jvmArgs = ['javaagent:../agent-v1.0.0/agent.jar']
    }
}
```

But this fails with:

> Could not determine the dependencies of task ':proj1'.
>
> Task with path 'javaagent:../agent-v1.0.0/agent.jar' not found in project ':proj1'.

I've tried this by putting the agent-v1.0.0 in both the root, and in each project, and it still fails. What am I missing?

Comment: At first blink it seems to me that you reference `../agent-v1.0.0/` from the root. Try without `../`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you wrapping that logic in a new `task`? And then passing the return from `jvmArgs` to `dependsOn`?

Just configure the test tasks correctly:

```
subprojects {
    tasks.withType(Test) {
        jvmArgs "-javaagent:${project.rootDir}/agent-v1.0.0/agent.jar"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A task can depend on another task. So `dependsOn` expects a **task** as argument. `test.jvmArgs = ['javaagent:../agent-v1.0.0/agent.jar']` is not a task.

If you want to **configure** all the test tasks of all subprojects to have additional jvm args, then the syntax would be

```
subprojects {
    // this block of code runs for every subproject

    afterEvaluate {
        // this block of code runs after the subproject has been evaluated, and thus after 
        // the test task has been added by the subproject build script

        test {
            // this block of code is used to configure the test task of the subproject

            // this configures the jvmArgs property of the test task
            jvmArgs = ['javaagent:../agent-v1.0.0/agent.jar']
        }
    }
}
```

But just don't copy and paste this code. Read the grade user guide, and learn its fundamental concepts.